# Doctrine: does an entity manager update in memory relations before flushing changes?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

Suppose I have 2 classes (Person, House) with a **bidirectional relationship** (a person has a list of houses and a house has an owner).

Suppose I had the following in the **Person** class:

```
$houses = new ArrayCollection();

public function removeHouse(id){
    $this->houses->remove(id);
}
```

Suppose you had a **Person** (with name: **John**) who owns a house and did the following:

```
$john = $em->find('User', $johnsId);
$johnsHouse = $john->getHouse(0); // this would give you John's first house

echo $house->getOwner()->getName(); // this would echo "John"

$user->removeHouse(0); // this would remove the house from John's list

echo $house->getOwner()->getName();
```

This is before the entity manager flushes anything. So my **first question: what would the last echo produce? null or "John"**

Then the flush occurs...

```
$em->flush();

echo $house->getOwner()->getName();
```

**Second question: what would the echo produce now? null or John?**

From what I understand from Doctrine's documentation, this should now produce null, right?

My goal is to have the other side of the bidirectional relation to reflect the change that occurred on this side before the flushing occurs. Put differently, I want the echo of the first question to produce null.

If this isn't done automatically by the entity manager before flushing (answer to first question is "John"), **do I have to fix it by performing the update on the other side manually by modding the removeHouse function?**

```
public function removeHouse(id){
    $house = $this->houses->remove(id);
    $house->setOwner(null)
}
```

And are there any complications this could have when the entity manager attempts to make the changes upon flushing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered the answers to my questions after stumbling upon the right page in the documentation. You, as the developer, are required to keep your relations in sync yourself.

See: 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html